# Is this bad database coding?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my DatabaseHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper I've set various methods to return Cursors to my other Activities so that I don't perform any queries within any other class except DatabaseHelper. In those methods I don't close the Cursor or database afterwards, and I return it like:

```
public Cursor getCoursesLeft()
{
    // Open a readable database.
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // Query the database and return the cursor.
    return database.query(DEGREE_PLAN_TABLE, null, DEGREE_COLUMN_TAKEN + " = ?",
            new String[] { "0" }, null, null, DEGREE_COLUMN_CLASS_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE");
}
```

From whichever Activity I call the method from, I do ensure to close the Cursor that's returned after I use it.

Since Cursor is an Object, it should pass by reference, correct? So closing it from the other Activity should close the original object, and if I understand it correctly closing the Cursor also closes the database.

Is this a bad coding practice?

It seems like randomly I'll get a LogCat error saying close was never called on the database and the only thing I can find in my code that might be the reason is how I return the Cursors in those methods.

Comment: It's fairly odd as a design. Generally it's desirable for one object or layer to "own" database cursors, manage them, and only "borrow" the cursors to other layers, or not expose them at all. I'd consider either returning the result of the whole database operation from wherever you start it. You could also use a callback pattern to make the other classes unaware of the cursor lifecycle. (See for example: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html )

Answer (score 1):

> and if I understand it correctly closing the Cursor also closes the
>   database.

That does not sound quite right. You have to explicitly close the **database after you've closed all cursors**. The logcat errors are due to you not closing the databse and probably attempting to open another instance of it.

The order is important, cursors first, then the DB instance.

```
<bad joke in 3.. 2.. 1...>
```

The rest does not sound like any bad practice, when you gotta db it you just gotta db it. :D

**[EDIT]**: You said you've done this:

```
public Cursor getCoursesLeft()
{
    // Open a readable database.
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
                   ^^^ here you're creating a new instance of the db
which means the db is opened for reading, and the scope of this variable
is lost outside this function. This means you can not close this instance explicitly

    // Query the database and return the cursor.
    return database.query(DEGREE_PLAN_TABLE, null, DEGREE_COLUMN_TAKEN + " = ?",
            new String[] { "0" }, null, null, DEGREE_COLUMN_CLASS_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE");
}
```

Instead have a database variable that you can access outside this method and close it once you're done working with the Cursor (and you've closed the cursor)

```
SQLiteDatabase database;
public Cursor getCoursesLeft()
{
    // Open a readable database.
    database = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // Query the database and return the cursor.
    return database.query(DEGREE_PLAN_TABLE, null, DEGREE_COLUMN_TAKEN + " = ?",
            new String[] { "0" }, null, null, DEGREE_COLUMN_CLASS_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE");
}
public void someOtherFunction() {
  Cursor blah = getCoursesLeft();
  // do something with blah
  blah.close();
  database.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you close the database before you use the Cursor, will that affect the Cursor accessing the data?

Comment: Never the database first. Always Cursors first, then the db instance.

Comment: Okay, so how would I close the database instance when all I have access to is the returned Cursor?

Comment: The best practice people use in this case is to put all DB access into a singleton class. This way only ONE instance of the DB is present at any given time. Have some static methods in this class to open and close the DB.

Comment: Is that not what I was doing by putting all database access into the DatabaseHelper extended class?

Comment: Well in that case I don't see why you don't have access to your database instance. That's the whole point of a Singleton class. You have a getInstance() method to get the instance of the private static database object you create. Simple.

Comment: I edited the post and added the method that is giving an error.

Comment: @Emrys90, added some details.

Comment: I actually found the reason I was getting this error. I feel like an idiot. I forgot to add the onDestroy method to this particular Activity, and so the DatabaseHelper instance was never closed and the database remained open.

Answer (score 0):

Not closing a cursor just causes memory leaks. Closing a database is different.

Closing a cursor is like closing a particular connection to certain `.file` files generated when the cursor is created.

Hence you should **ALWAYS** close your cursor.

Is this bad coding?

No, and yea. Don't let your Activity mess around with those temp files. While nothing will happen it just doesn't seem nice

Comment: I did close the Cursor, after the Activity is done using it. I'm getting database not closed errors, not Cursor ones.

Comment: You have to run the `db.close()` method after your done with the database. Otherwise that error will show up

Comment: How do I do that from the current code I have? Will I have to change how I handle returned data?

Comment: It wouldn't be like that. You create an instance of your custom Database Class. So either close it when your done with the instance. OR if you need data throughout your app. Create a static class Database and close the database in the `onPause()`

Comment: Right now I have it instanced in the onCreate of most Activities, and closed in the onDestroy. You're saying I should change it to close it as soon as I'm done with any data calls?

Comment: Might be a better option to save memory leaks but it should only cause this error if you leave the activity. (If you get this error anywhere other than the onPause.. Well you might have a bigger issue) But assuming you don't leaving activity in any way including messages coming will cause the error

Comment: I actually found the reason I was getting this error. I feel like an idiot. I forgot to add the onDestroy method to this particular Activity, and so the DatabaseHelper instance was never closed and the database remained open.